# Quais frameworks de programação orientada a aspectos existem para .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-aspectos

Pesquisando sobre [programação orientada a aspectos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto), encontrei um framework que implementa esse paradigma, o [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/products).

Porém essa ferramenta é paga para algumas features.

Alguém conhece mais alguma?

Answer (score 5):

Tem vários. Fiz uma lista:

- [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features)
- [LOOM.NET](http://loom.codeplex.com/)
- [Aspect.NET](http://aspectdotnet.codeplex.com/)
- [Enterprise Library 3.0 Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)
- [AspectDNG](http://aspectdng.tigris.org/)
- [DotSpect](http://dotspect.tigris.org/) (.SPECT)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Wicca](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~eaddy/wicca/)
- [Seasar.NET](http://s2container.net.seasar.org/en/index.html)
- [Aspect#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspectsharp/)
- [Puzzle.NAspect](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/01/08/naspect-the-first-debuggable-aop-framework-for-net/)
- [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)
- [Unity Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660891%28PandP.20%29.aspx)